# About Oscillation in Gravitational wave

Tags: general-relativity, waves, gravity, spacetime, gravitational-waves

I am a high school student studying about gravitational waves. I hope they are similar to other waves like sound waves, etc. So I what to know exactly what oscillates in a gravitational wave. Like in sound waves, density of a medium oscillates over its maximum and minimum value. I wonder what could be oscillating?

Answer (score 0):

In general, a wave is a  disturbance traveling in some medium. For example, a sound wave is a disturbance travelling through air. A wave at the beach is a disturbance travelling through the water. A light wave (which does not need a medium) is a disturbance in the electromagnetic field, traveling as an oscillating electromagnetic wave.

Gravitational waves are disturbances or ripples in spacetime.

> I wonder what could be oscillating?

Following the same logic, it is spacetime itself that is oscillating.

> I hope they are similar to other waves like sound waves, etc. So I what to know exactly what oscillates in a gravitational wave.

Gravitational waves are different in their structure. They are emitted from a system when the system has a time varying (mass) [quadrupole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_formula).

Comment: What does it mean for a spacetime to oscillate? Please clarify.